# Changing Logo on Scroll with PHP/jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, css

Ello there,

First of all thanks for any help, it's appreciated.

What I am trying to do is change my website's logo on scroll, but I am trying to accomplish this through my theme options, and I am not looking to use CSS to hide/show a class which uses the background property to display the logo.

Instead in my header.php I am echoing a function which renders the logo dependent on what "header option" a user has selected.

Here is the PHP I have which works on a switch inside my admin panel, so if a user selects "Yes" and they would like to change the logo when the header is sticky then they have an option to upload an extra logo (this all works fine without checking if that css class exists):

```
$site_logo_change_scroll_switch = notorious_options('site_logo_change_scroll_switch');

if ( $site_logo_change_scroll_switch == true && class_exists('scrolled-nt') ) {
    $logo_url = notorious_options('site_logo_change_scroll', false, 'url');
}

return $logo_url;
```

This code is all working fine, except for checking if the CSS class "scrolled-nt" exists to only display this logo on scroll. I am using Jquery to append this class to my logo:

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function(){
    var fromTopPx = 5;
    var scrolledFromtop = jQuery(window).scrollTop();
    if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
        jQuery('.nt-logo').addClass('scrolled-nt');
    }else{
        jQuery('.nt-logo').removeClass('scrolled-nt');
    }
});
```

I can see on my website, that when I scroll down the extra CSS class "scrolled-nt" is added onto my img src, but the logo is not showing at all after or before scroll, with checking if this CSS class exists (in my php above).

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

I hope I explained this properly, and maybe it is a simple fix, but I am fairly new to JS/PHP and quickly getting an addiction for it.

Any helps appreciated, thanks!

Comment: show your css-class `scrolled-nt`

Comment: Are you barely interacting PHP and JS with those snippets?

Comment: There is nothing on the css class "scrolled-nt", have only appended it to the logo img src on scroll.

Comment: Sorry Chay22, not sure by what you mean?

Comment: Your Problem is that by the time you check if that class exits your jquery code wasn't even running yet. jquery got executed client side. php is serverside. so class_exists will always give false.

Comment: Thanks Tommy, that makes perfect sense. So what would be the best way to fix this?